# LinkedIn V2 Profile API not properly returning email

Tags: linkedin-api

I am attempting to use the LinkedIn V2 Profile API to aid in signups for my website.
I have properly implemented the "Sign in with LinkedIn" button on my website, set up the OAuth 2.0 callback, and my server properly swaps the OAuth 2.0 Access Code for the user's Access Token. 
To do this, I am using the Python linkedin_v2 library linked [here](https://github.com/HootsuiteLabs/python-linkedin-v2).

I am then attempting to grab the user's profile, and obtain their first name, last name, and email, to store in my database as a method of signup. I have confirmed that my application requests r_emailaddress, r_liteprofile, and r_member_social accesses.

To obtain their profile, I have attempted the following methods:

1. Using the Python Library linked above to create an application with the users access token and request the profile as follows:

```
    application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(token=accessToken)

    profile = application.get_profile()
```

Unfortunately, this method only returns the user's first name, last name, and id, even when I include `selectors=['email-address']` as a parameter to the `get_profile()` function, as specified by the library documentation.

2. Sending a `GET` request using the Python `requests` library `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/(id:{person ID})` with headers that include `Authentication: Bearer {user access token}`.

Unfortunately, this method results in a `403` (forbidden) error.

I am curious of the following things:

1. Why do I obtain a `403` when querying the Profile API using the request library, when the same access token works to query the API through the Python linkedin_v2 library?
2. Does anyone know of how to use the [python_linkedin_v2](https://github.com/HootsuiteLabs/python-linkedin-v2) library to obtain an email address with the profile?
3. Does anyone know of a better library to use in order to accomplish my goal of obtaining profile information regarding users whom are logging into my product using linkedin?
4. Do I need any additional permissions in order to access my users' emails from LinkedIn?

Thank you so much for your help, and I look forward to discussing potential solutions with all of you.

-Rob